# Error: Attribute must be grouped or in aggregate function NETEZZA SQL

Tags: sql, netezza

I'm writing a SQL to create a calendar table as below and getting error "Attribute T1.CALENDAR_DATE must be grouped or used in an aggregate function

Code I've written is

```
WITH CALENDAR AS
(
SELECT
EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM DATE(NOW()-1)-T1.CALENDAR_DATE)/7 AS ROLLING_WEEK,
MIN(T1.WEEK_OF_YEAR) AS WEEK,
MAX(T1.CALENDAR_DATE) AS LAST_DAY_WEEK,
MIN(T1.CALENDAR_DATE) AS FIRST_DAY_WEEK

FROM DIM_GINZ_DATE AS T1
WHERE T1.ROLLING_MONTH BETWEEN 0 AND 84
GROUP BY T1.ROLLING_WEEK
)

SELECT *
FROM CALENDAR
```

What would be the issue here?

Thanks :)

Comment: Try using:  `group by EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM DATE(NOW()-1)-T1.CALENDAR_DATE)/7`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `T1.CALENDAR_DATE` in `GROUP by` or use some aggregate function on `EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM DATE(NOW()-1)-T1.CALENDAR_DATE)/7`

```
WITH CALENDAR AS
(
SELECT
EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM DATE(NOW()-1)-T1.CALENDAR_DATE)/7 AS ROLLING_WEEK,
-- something like this need to be implemented if you dont want to group by T1.CALENDAR_DATE
-- EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM DATE(NOW()-1)-MIN(T1.CALENDAR_DATE))/7 AS ROLLING_WEEK 
MIN(T1.WEEK_OF_YEAR) AS WEEK,
MAX(T1.CALENDAR_DATE) AS LAST_DAY_WEEK,
MIN(T1.CALENDAR_DATE) AS FIRST_DAY_WEEK

FROM DIM_GINZ_DATE AS T1
WHERE T1.ROLLING_MONTH BETWEEN 0 AND 84
GROUP BY T1.ROLLING_WEEK
, T1.CALENDAR_DATE -- like this
-- or use EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM DATE(NOW()-1)-T1.CALENDAR_DATE)/7
)

SELECT *
FROM CALENDAR
```

You can not use the unaggregated column in `select` clause if they are not in a `group by` clause, if used.